# UIWebView: Images are not updating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am using UIWebView to load HTML Page. From that HTML I have generated PDF file. My PDF file content changes as per the HTML data changes. when I change the Signature(Image) of the user in application respective PDF will not change to new signature. It shows the previous signature.

How can I reload that UIWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using same url with updated content use this.

```
UIWebView*  webV=[[UIWebView alloc]init];

NSString* htmlString= @"Loading...";

[webV loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

[webV loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mainURL]];
```

Answer (score 2):

`[webView reload]` should do the trick.

If you are using a new URL you can use `[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL]];`

Comment: thanks. I have tried [webView relaod]; But still not get any success. I am using  [webView loadHTMLString:contentOfFile baseURL:nil]; :(