# images are not updating in the webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using the below code,

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlfilepath];
NSURLRequest * request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]; 
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

All the contents from `html` are updating to `pdf` except the `signature`.

[UIWebView: Images are not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578275/uiwebview-images-are-not-updating/37938048#37938048)

But I am still facing the same problem.

Comment: I guess that the file is local, the path of the images is correct? If you check the html code, get the image, and try to show it into a UIImageView with that path, does it work?

Comment: yes the image is getting stored locally, in the same folder where the html and pdf files are stored. But the image is showing properly in html but when i am converting html file to pdf by passing the html file path as url its not reflecting in pdf. 
Except the image signature remaining all the contents are reflecting properly from html to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same url with updated content use this.

```
UIWebView*  webV=[[UIWebView alloc]init];

NSString* htmlString= @"Loading...";

[webV loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

[webV loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mainURL]];
```